# onClick loop through matching API properties/products - ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, function, api, loops, onclick

Need some people! :)

I'm trying to build a fake product page for mobile phones, using ReactJS.

1. I have a simple react app, where my **API data is stored in state**, in app.js, (not a database or axios request).
2. I'm passing I have this data stored in **this.state.phones**
3. And passing this data to a component called **Gold.js**
4. I can then loop through my data.

**HOWEVER....**

When a user clicks on an phone color, for example Gold, Space Grey, or Silver, I want all the state data on my page to change.  I'm using handleClick.

For example, my image should change, price and product description, depending on which color you have clicked.

Here's how the app is currently working:
https://codesandbox.io/s/kpo51ppxv

However, when you click on the coloured squares, (onClick/HandleClick), I'm not sure what the best way is, to loop through the matching data and make the correct data appear.

**So far, I have sliced my data .slice(0,1), to only make the first product appear on the page...**

Ps - not sure why the images are not appearing in the link, but they are there in assets...  I've also consoled logged everything so you can take a look at console.

Thanks! Please help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass `color` when listening clicks a color box.

You can see my code here: https://codesandbox.io/s/yq31lp0poj

Comment: amazing thank you!  Quick question - why did you set currentcolor state to 0?

Comment: Also, why did you change the handclick function to start this way?
  handleClick = color => e => { } . Would it still be the same as . handleClick = (color, e) => {} . Thanks!

Comment: Also, what does this line mean?  iphones={[
            this.state.phones[0].deviceSummary[this.state.currentColor]
          ]} Passing two states at once?

Comment: hey @Max - if I went to also sort, by Memory size, (i've updated the link), what's the best way to do this?  I've added two buttons and if I click on "64MB", and then click on a color, the api data defaults back to those colors of 256MB...
https://codesandbox.io/s/545q4qo52x